# Is there any relation between the orders of consecutive elements of a cyclic group?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, finite-groups

Consider the multiplicative cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_p=\{1,2,\cdots,p-1\}$,
where $p$ is prime. Let $a,a+1\in\mathbb{Z}_p$. Is there any relation between
the orders of $a$ and $a+1$? I guess
that, usually, there is none. But perhaps I am wrong; if there is some, I would like to know
about it.

What really interests me is a sort of a "negative'' result. I explain:

I usually work in finite fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ (or $GF(p^n)$, if you
prefer this notation; these are fields with $p^n$ elements, with $p$ an odd
prime) and deal with subgroups of
$\mathbb{F}_{p^n}\backslash\{0\}=\mathbb{F}^\ast_{p^n}$.

Let $\omega\in\mathbb{F}_{p^n}^*$ be an element of order $(p^{2s}-1)$ (with
$0<s<n$) and consider elements in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ of the form
$s_j=\omega^j(1+\omega^{(p^s-1)j})$, where $j$ goes from $0$ to $p^s$.

I would like to show that there is some $j_0$, in this range, such that the
order of $(1+\omega^{(p^s-1)j_0})$ does not divide $p^{2s}-1$, the order of
$\omega$.

This would imply that $(\omega^{j_0})^{p^{2s}-1}=1$ but $(s_{j_0})^{p^{2s}-1}\neq 1$.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: "Consecutive" is not preserved under isomorphism. So it is not so clear what it means in general.

Comment: If you look at the statistics of values of a multiplicative character on $k$ consecutive integers in $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$, every feasible pattern will occur roughly equally often if $p$ is large compared to $k$ (you want $k = 2$). See Theorem A.1 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/QuadraticResiduePatterns.pdf, which is a more general statement (general finite fields, possibly different nontrivial characters being used in different positions).  Since the order of an element is determined by which nontrivial characters are trivial on it, this suggests no predictable pattern.